# Kotlin: Required: kotlin.Boolean. Found: kotlin.Boolean?

Tags: kotlin

I wrote a condition as below

```
    if (subsriber?.isUnsubscribed && isDataEmpty()) {
        loadData()
    }
```

As my subscriber could be null. The above title error displayed. So I cast it as below

```
    if (subsriber?.isUnsubscribed as Boolean && isDataEmpty()) {
        loadData()
    }
```

It looks not as nice. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I usually resolve this situation with the `?:` operator:

```
if (subsriber?.isUnsubscribed ?: false && isDataEmpty()) {
    loadData()
}
```

This way, if `subscriber` is `null`, `subsriber?.isUnsubscribed` is also `null` and `subsriber?.isUnsubscribed ?: false` evaluates to `false`, which is hopefully the intended result, otherwise switch to `?: true`.

Also casting a nullable type with `as Boolean` is [unsafe](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html) and will throw an exception if `null` is encountered.

Comment: I like this Elvis operator. This is what I'm looking for. Great! Thanks!

Comment: You can also write `subscriber?.isUnsubscribed == true` which I find clearer.

Comment: I specifically created `.flat()` extension function for optional booleans to flatten it to a `false`.

Answer (score 12):

Also is you have just **Required: kotlin.Boolean. Found: kotlin.Boolean**? you can do this:

```
when(something?.isEmpty()) {
    true ->  {  }
    false -> {  }
    null ->  {  }
}
```

Also if you are interested only in **one simple conditional statement**

```
if(something?.isEmpty() == true){
  this will only worked if not null && empty
}
```

*i know it's answered question but for future viewers can be helpful*

Comment: I don't see why `something?.isEmpty()` doesn't work but `something?.isEmpty() == true` is working.

Comment: @Lechucico that simple. In kotlin when you have ? it means that it can return null.
So you have 3 outcomes, true, false, null (cus you said by ? sign that can be null)
Now if you are interested in only one outcome, like empty, you have to do isEmpty, which will return true, if it exists and its empty. If it doesn't exists it will return nulll, so NULL !=  true. It's not what you were looking for, and you still get proper validation. In other words. Pass only on true, null and false are rejected by this logical validation.

Answer (score 7):

Another way to resolve this issue is to explicitly check if the expression is `true`:

```
if (subsriber?.isUnsubscribed == true && isDataEmpty()) {
    loadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*If* `subscriber` is `val`,

```
subscriber != null && subscriber.isUnsubscribed && isDataEmpty()
```

will work. As a bonus, `subscriber != null` will be known inside the `if` block and you can call methods on `subscriber` without `?.` or `!!.`.