# How can I store document field data from a particular collection in firestore database to a string variable in kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get data from the cloud firestore and have to store it to a string variable but unable to do so and need help.

This is below code

```
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        val docRef = db.collection("SlideShowImages").document("1")
        docRef.get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                if (document != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: ${document.data}")
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "No such document")
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", exception)
            }
```

---

getting this from database and I want **Link** to store to **variable first_image**

```
{about=FCB, link=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/missionx-g6305.appspot.com/o/EVENTS%2FSlide%20Show%20Images%2FCurrent%2FFCB.jpg?alt=media&token=950c5200-c553-4639-b33e-2b91a220b19c}
```

---

And I want to store it in variable

```
val first_image : String

first_image = document.data.link
```

when I use this I am getting an error

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Unable to store LINK field in variable

Comment: @PeterHaddad he didn't try to implement get Method to retrieve the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and put the variable type `var` so you can modify value. `Val` only allowed to set value permenant to that variable.

```
private var first_image: String
```

and get image in your variable :

```
first_image = document.getString("link");
```

Read Difference between [val and var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200075/val-and-var-in-kotlin).

Comment: Yeah thanks, but it's showing TYPE MISMATCH. Required: String , Found: string?

Comment: is your field nullable ? try to put question mark on assigning

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54311577/error-requiredstring-foundstring-kotlin-and-android-studio check this